# Does Redis EXPIREAT remove itself on a GET?

Tags: redis

According to Redis documentaiton, [EXPIREAT](https://redis.io/commands/expireat) has the 'exact same effect and semantic as [EXPIRE](https://redis.io/commands/expire)'.

EXPIRE invalidates itself when a key is retrieved via `GET`. There is no mention in the `EXPIREAT` documentation of a similar behaviour, but it would not make sense for `EXPIREAT` to no longer expire upon key retrieval.

Due to the vague nature of the documentation I am unable to tell what the actual behaviour of `EXPIREAT` is in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually expiring itself when the key is retrieved is not the only way, [according to documentation](https://redis.io/commands/expire#how-redis-expires-keys)

Redis keys are expired in two ways: a passive way, and an active way.

- A key is passively expired simply when some client tries to access it, and the key is found to be timed out.
- Of course this is not enough as there are expired keys that will never be accessed again. These keys should be expired anyway, so periodically Redis tests a few keys at random among keys with an expire set. All the keys that are already expired are deleted from the keyspace.

For your question;

There is a generic expire function in the Redis [codebase](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/75f9dec64455ed500277922baf7f371a7eb294a4/src/expire.c#L500) and in the comments section it says

> This is the generic command implementation for EXPIRE, PEXPIRE, EXPIREAT and PEXPIREAT.

"my optimistic guess" is that these different expire( or *at) commands invoke this function with different parameters by making a conversion. So `EXPIREAT` command also has the same behavior as `EXPIRE` and the keys are expired with the same two ways.

Comment: That is really annoying - I don't think that is a logical way to handle `EXPIREAT`. Using `EXPIREAT` would indicate you actually want it to expire at that time regardless... Regardless, thank you for the answer

Comment: actually it doesn't affect expire behavior @Alfie - both expire and expireat work same and they will expire at whether the after the given seconds or timestamps.